# Longest set in a dict of sets

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a defaultdict of sets and I need to align columns nicely during final output
Each set is displayed via `",".join(setdict[key])` to avoid ugly braces
I'm wondering is there more efficient and Pythonic way to calc longest set's string with commas
My current implementation is

```
def GetSetLen(setdict):
    maxset = 0
    for k,v in setdict.iteritems():
        maxset = max(maxset, (len(",".join(setdict[k]))))
    return maxset
```

Real example of my dict:

```
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'2235788': set(['604', '2415919103', '7']), '3674877': set(['604', '2415919103', '7'])})
```

Comment: Please show samples of your data, this does not look like a good approach to get the length of a set and may contain errors

Comment: This script is some application's log parser. I perform search thru the log and find mappings of ID and errors for each ID. So you can assume I have an ID and list (actually set, because log can contain repetitions of error) of errors. Finally I need to output column of IDs, column of assosiated errors and some others colmns

Comment: I just mean that this site requires you to create a simple example of what your `setdict` looks like, even with sample values, so the question is self contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dict.itervalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) because the code does not take account of keys. And you don't need to make a temporary string to calculate length of the joined strings.

```
if not setdict:
    return 0  # max(empty_setdict) raise a `ValueError`
return max(sum(map(len, v)) + len(v) - 1 if v else 0
           for v in setdict.itervalues())
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to somehow use `str(v)` or `map(lambda v: len(str(v)) ...)` to account for `__str__` changes?

Comment: @ReutSharabani, OP used `','.join`; which means that the elements of sets are already strings.

Comment: It works and I accept it, but could you pls add a few words more explaining how it works, as I learn Python just 1 week and it's not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: @user1542755, [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) accepts any iterable object as an argument in addition to accepting multiple parameters. In other words, both `max([1, 2, 3])`, `max(1, 2, 3)` and `max(1, max(2, 3))` work.

Comment: @user1542755, In the answer code, I passed generator using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). If you are not familiar with generator, look [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) first.

Comment: I know abt list comprehension, but I more confused with condition
Map function applies len() to all v - that's clear, but further logic is not clear still. I guess len of v is decreased if v is not Null or not decreased if v is Null

Comment: `x if condition else y` is called [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (similar to a ternary operator in C): `x` is returned if the condition is true, otherwise `y` is returned. That was used to handle empty set case.

Answer (score 0):

`map` `str.join` on the values ,then map `len` on the resultant strings, then find the `max`

```
>>> 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'2235788': set(['604', '2415919103', '7']), '654321': ['60004', '2415919103', '765'], '000002': ['', '', ''], '000000': [''], '3674877': set(['604', '2415919103', '7']), '123456': ['604', '2415919103', '765']})
>>> map(len, map(','.join, d.itervalues()))
[16, 20, 2, 0, 16, 18]
>>> max(map(len, map(','.join, d.itervalues())))
20
>>>
```

You could use [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) if you didn't want to create the intermediate lists.